# Adaptive Performance Installation Error (Unity 2D)

Tags: unity-game-engine

When trying to build my Unity 2D project, I keep encountering this error:

> "No Adaptive Performance provider package installed. Adaptive Performance requires a provider to get information during runtime. Please install a provider such as Adaptive Performance Samsung (Android) from the Adaptive Performance Settings."

I have checked under project settings and package manager and Adaptive Performance 3.0.2 is installed, so I don't know why I keep encountering this error.

I have already tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I think it asks you to install a **provider** package.

Answer (score 0):

**In "Untity 2021.3.4f1 Personal":**
[image: "No Adaptive Performance provider package installed"]

**Current setup:**
[image: Project settings]

**This worked for me:**
[image: Remove it!]

**That is, remove it. Note! I am working with WebGL as target platform but got this error regardless target type.**

(And yes, there are surely some drawbacks with this solution BUT just to get rid of the problem can make anyone a little bit happier...)

*Best of luck!*

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: Install "Samsung Android Provider" through project settings.

1. Select **Edit** > **Project Settings** > **Adaptive Performance**.
2. Open the **Android Settings** tab and, in the **Providers** section, select **Samsung Android Provider**.
3. The installed providers can be managed in Package Manager.
   [image]

**Btw**:

1. Adaptive Performance is for mobile device or device emulator. If you only want to build WebGL, just remove "Adaptive Performance" from Package Manager. just like Mr Jernberg's solution in the previous answer.
2. refer to: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.adaptiveperformance.samsung.android@5.0/manual/getting-started.html